# Qt 'Rectangle' is not a type - when rectangle is declared as a class

Tags: c++, qt

Im having a problem of my Rectangle class not being seen as a type.  I've included the proper header, and so I am confused.

shapes.h

```
#ifndef SHAPES_H
#define SHAPES_H

#include "Colors.h"
#include <QPoint>
#include "glwidget.h"

//class GLWidget;

class Shape
{
    public:

        virtual void draw();
};

class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public:
        Rectangle(GLWidget *w, QPoint tl, QPoint br){
            glWidget = w;
            topLeft = tl;
            btmRight = br;
        }

        virtual void draw(){
              // top horizontal
            for(int i = topLeft.x(); i < btmRight.x(); i++){
                 glWidget->setPixel(i,topLeft.y(), color);
             }
        }

    private:
        QPoint topLeft,btmRight;
        GLWidget *glWidget;
        RGBColor color;
};

#endif // SHAPES_H
```

glwidget.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtOpenGL>

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "glwidget.h"

#include "Shapes.h"

#ifndef GL_MULTISAMPLE
#define GL_MULTISAMPLE  0x809D
#endif

// ...   a bunch of code that doesn't need to be included

void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton){
        // do some drawing stuff
        QPoint mPos = event->pos();

        switch(drawmode)
        {
            case 1:
               currentShape = new Rectangle(this,mPos, mPos);  /***  This is the error ***/
        }

    }
}
```

glwidget.h

```
#ifndef AGLWIDGET_H
#define AGLWIDGET_H

#include <QGLWidget>

#include "Colors.h"

class Shape;

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();

    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
    QSize sizeHint() const;

    void setPixel(int x, int y, RGBColor c);

public slots:
    void setColor(RGBColor c);
    void setDrawRectangle();

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

private:

    QPoint lastPos;
    QVector<QPoint> drawPoints;
    RGBColor paintColor;
    int drawmode;
    Shape *currentShape;

};
```

Sorry for the load of code...  the exact error is 
'Rectangle' is not a type    glwidget.cpp  line 85

Anybody have an idea why it wouldn't be seeing Rectangle as a type in glwidget.cpp despite my including "Shapes.h"?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: nope.  I've literally pruned all my warnings and errors down.  All I get is 'Rectangle' is not a type.  I hate my computer some times.  Rectangle IS a type computer, why don't you ever listen to me!

Comment: How are you building?  Just wondering, cause it looks like this would compile in a regular C++ compiler (if you removed the mention of 'slots' and such)...which leads me to believe there's something Qt's expecting that isn't right.

Comment: Preprocess your code (e.g. `g++ -E`) and confirm what the compiler is seeing, then you should be able to figure out why.

Comment: Very odd, but when I got home and ran the code on my mac I got a different error.  It complained about my declaring a virtual function without defining it as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307352/g-undefined-reference-to-typeinfo   I fixed that error and it now runs fine on my mac.  I'll see if that also fixes the windows error despite their being different error messages...   Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm gonna go with it had something to do with the virtual function within Shape not being defined as in [g++ undefined reference to typeinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307352/g-undefined-reference-to-typeinfo).  The machine I had the strange error on is using an older version of Qt than I have on my personal machine, and my personal is having no issues with this code.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone, but I'm just gonna put this one to rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a longshot, but are you sure you're using  moc correctly in regards to the GLWidget code? IE, have you added `#include "glwidget.moc` to the .cpp file or included it in your build system (qmake knows to do this for you), as well as running moc first. I only mention this because forgetting to do this many moons ago caused me to see a pile of inscrutable type-related warnings and errors.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps somewhere in the ancestry of GLWidget there is a method or member called Rectangle and there is a confusion. See the documentation for GLWidget and its ancestors

Comment: If that were the case, the error would be more like "no suitable method Rectangle::Rectangle(GLWidget, int, int)" or something, rather than flat out saying Rectangles don't exist.

Comment: @cHao: It's not saying `Rectangle` doesn't exist, it's saying it's not a type, which could happen if it's a non-type name inherited from a base class. @wallacer: try using its fully-qualified name (`::Rectangle`), and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the compiler believes `Rectangle` [is a template](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/952/)