# Undefined reference to typeinfo when linking with nsRunnable

Tags: c++, gecko

As firefox 12 sdk removed the 'Proxy' object, I wanted to use [cross-thread calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/Making_cross-thread_calls_using_runnables) using nsRunnable. I basically did copy-and paste of the code:

```
class NotifyTask : public nsRunnable
{
public:
  NotifyTask(nsISupports *subject, const char *topic, bool remref)
    : mWorkerThread(do_GetCurrentThread())
  {
    MOZ_ASSERT(!NS_IsMainThread()); // This should be running on the worker thread
  }

  NS_IMETHOD Run() {
    MOZ_ASSERT(NS_IsMainThread()); // This method is supposed to run on the main thread!

    mWorkerThread->Shutdown();
    return NS_OK;
  }

private:
  nsCOMPtr<nsIThread> mWorkerThread;
};
```

And I tried to compile it. I got following errors:

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x -Wall -O2 -c  -DUSE_LIBUSB -fPIC -DHAVE_CRYPTO -fpermissive -DCRYPTPP -fshort-wchar -I../../xulrunner-sdk/include -o gipsy.o gipsy.cpp
gipsy.cpp:74:7: warning: ‘NotifyTask’ declared with greater visibility than the type of its field ‘NotifyTask::<anonymous>’ [-Wattributes]
gipsy.cpp:74:7: warning: ‘NotifyTask’ declared with greater visibility than its base ‘nsRunnable’ [-Wattributes]
g++ -std=gnu++0x -Wl,-z,defs -Wall -Os -o gipsy.so -shared gipsy.o gipsymodule.o tracklog.o gpslib/data.o gpslib/garmin.o gpslib/gps.o gpslib/phys.o gpslib/igc.o gpslib/aircotec.o cp1250.o prefparser.o gpslib/foreignigc.o gpslib/mlr.o gpslib/flymaster.o gpslib/compeo.o gpslib/iq.o ../libs/libcryptopp.a -lusb -L../../xulrunner-sdk/lib -lxpcomglue_s -lxul -lxpcom -lplds4 -lplc4 -lnspr4 -lpthread -ldl -lmozalloc
gipsy.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI10NotifyTask[typeinfo for NotifyTask]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for nsRunnable'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

According to [g++ undefined reference to typeinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307352/g-undefined-reference-to-typeinfo) it might be that gecko sdk was built with -fvisibility=hidden and some weird 'key method in different .so'. Is this an error in Gecko sdk or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gecko SDK is not link with RTTI - adding "-fno-rtti" parameter to the particular .o file fixed the problem.