# C++: what are the causes of " undefined reference to 'typeinfo for [class name]' "other than virtual functions

Tags: c++

some of these errors are solved by modifying

```
    virtual void draw();
```

to

```
    virtual void draw() {};
```

BUT, what can be the other causes of these errors?, other than virtual functions..
What can be the cause of the following error..

```
  /tmp/cciGEgp5.o:(.rodata._ZTI14CustomXmppPump[typeinfo for CustomXmppPump]+0x18): 
  undefined reference to `typeinfo for XmppPump'
```

Comment: Perhaps you have just the .h or .hpp file in the build, without the corresponding .cpp file

Comment: You're confusing declarations and definitions.

Comment: Looks like you're compiling without RTTI. Note that the undefined reference is for the **typeinfo** not for the actual virtual function. This is a ["known issue"](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/issues/detail?id=143) that you find on the libjingle site, too.

Comment: did compile with -frtti flag.. this is the compile code..
g++ -g -Wall -DPOSIX -frtti -DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH -DFEATURE_ENABLE_SSL -DHAVE_OPENSSL_SSL_H=1 -I ../ -frtti pcp_main.cc ../talk/build/dbg/lib/libxmpphelp.a ../talk/build/dbg/lib/libjingle.a ../talk/build/dbg/lib/libexpat.a ../talk/build/dbg/lib/libsrtp.a -lpthread -lssl .. still get the same error though :(... any ideas?

Comment: @Damon great that you guessed it was libjingle... :D.. it would be so helpful if you could correct my compile code... this error is driving me nuts...

Answer (score 12):

If you're compiling with RTTI (-frtti), make sure your dependent libraries are also compiled with it, and not -fno-rtti. Otherwise you will get the typeinfo error when you subclass a class compiled with -fno-rtti  or use dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 9):

In GCC, the first non-inline virtual method is used to determine the the translation unit where the vtable and typeinfo objects are created.   If you then do not define that method, it creates the error you see, since it expected you define that method somewhere, and was waiting for that definition to emit the output of the vtable and typeinfo for the class.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html

When you change the declaration of `virtual void draw();` to the inline definition of `virtual void draw() {};`, it picks a different function to emit the vtable.

Comment: unless all definitions of virtuals are visible. in that case, every TU which includes it could get its own copy (bad).

Comment: @Justin:  Correct.  It causes additional bloat in the object code, which has to be eliminated by the linker, which can be time consusming.