# Undefined symbol while using boost:regex_error in C++?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using boost library for regular expression, I used boost::regex() function to compile the regular expression. I have to catch the exception thrown by this function call. So I used `boost:regex_error` in catch().

But the use of this function gives following error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZTIN5boost11regex_errorE
```

What is the reason of above error?

Comment: You need to link with the boost regex library (which you will have to build first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to link with `boost_regex`. On GCC, add `-lboost_regex` to your linker invocation. Other compilers will have equivalent options.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ c++filt _ZTIN5boost11regex_errorE
typeinfo for boost::regex_error
```

So typeinfo is missing. I think you should compile your project with RTTI (run time type information) enabled.

or

[g++ undefined reference to typeinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307352/g-undefined-reference-to-typeinfo)