# How to use boost::wregex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I used wregex as the following C++ codes. But it does not work, could you help me? any advices are welcome.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
namespace abc
{
    int ClassName::fun1()
    {
        wstring wp1 = _String2Wstring(p1); // This a function defined by myself.
        boost::wregex wreg(wp1,boost::regex::perl|boost::regbase::icase);
        ......
    }
}
```

I can compile a .so file successfully in centos 7. But when I start my application. I get the following message in the log file by the website http://demangler.com/

```
undefined symbol: boost::basic_regex<wchar_t, 
boost::regex_traits<wchar_t, boost::cpp_regex_traits<wchar_t> > 
>::do_assign(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, unsigned int)
```

And if delete the following code, I can start my application. So I think the error is from this code. But I am confused to find the answer. Thanks.

```
boost::wregex wreg(wp1,boost::regex::perl|boost::regbase::icase);
```

Comment: The error you see is a *linker error*. It happens because you didn't include a boost regex library in your build.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559179/linking-to-boost-regex-in-gcc/559191#559191, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21863253/3832970, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11985138/3832970

Comment: Not that `_String2Wstring` is a reserved name in global namespace - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not saying to your linker to link against boost_regex. 
If you are using GCC, add linker flag `-lboost_regex`. Other compilers require similar flags.

Comment: I use cmake and make to compile my project. How to add the linker flag? I try to find the answer through google, but failed.

Comment: have a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646518/855844