# can't access my inherited class attributes

Tags: c++, linux, dns

I am working on a project for my job to encode/decode into buffers DNS Records objects in C++. Some records have the same infos, so I created a class Dns message with theses basic infos:

```
class CDnsMessage
{
public:
    CDnsMessage();
    virtual ~CDnsMessage();

    virtual int GetSize() = 0;
    uint32_t       m_ttl; 
    DnsClass       dclass; 
    DnsType        type; 
    std::string    m_domain;    
};
```

The `DnsClass` and `DnsTypes` are enum with the differents class/types I use. Then I have my sub-classes for each record, I will take A for the example:

```
class CDns_RR_A : public CDnsMessage
{
public:
    CDns_RR_A();

    virtual ~CDns_RR_A();
    virtual int GetSize(CDnsMessage const& msg);

    uint32_t        m_address;
};
```

Then I have my encode/decode function in another header, `encoder.h` and `encoder.cpp`.

I am receiving a `DnsMessage` (the object) and receiving buffer, and I encode or decode. So I used dynamic cast to know which type of record it is, and adapt the encode and decode to the variables the object has.
here is my decode for example:

```
EncodeResult DecodeData(const char * buffer,CDnsMessage & msg,std::size_t size)
{
    EncodeResult res(ENCODE_OK);

    uint32 ttl = 0;
    eDnsClass dnsclass;
    eDnsType  dnstype;

    //decoding RR_A
    if(CDns_RR_A* RR_A_msg = dynamic_cast< CDns_RR_A* >( &msg ))
    {       
        uint32_t address;

        dnsclass = CLASS_IN;
        msg.dclass = dnsclass;
        dnstype = TYPE_A;
        msg.type = dnstype;

        res = DecodeInt32(&buffer,&size,&ttl);
        CHECK_DECODE_ERROR(res);
        msg.m_ttl = ttl;

        res = DecodeInt32(&buffer,&size,&address);
        CHECK_DECODE_ERROR(res);
        msg.m_address = address;
    }
}
```

The `DecodeInt32` is a function made by people before long time ago, it takes a buffer (`char**`), a `size_t*` and a `uint32`.

I have two problems, first I can't access the members of my subclass, when I compile I got a problem with msg.dclass or msg.type and It says "request for member 'class' in 'RR_A_msg', which is of non-class type 'CDns_RR_A*'
but I don't understand, if my dynamic cast works it mean that the msg received waiting to be fulfilled is of type A no?

And my second problem is: I am using `uint32_t` for the ttl (imposed by enterprise) and my `decodeint32` takes `uint32` so the compiler says *`invalid conversion from uint32_t* to uint32`*.

Is there  away to convert one to another?

Edit: 
Updated my code following answers and advices, now i have

```
if(dynamic_cast< CDns_RR_A* >( &msg ) != nullptr)
                            {       
                                    CDns_RR_A* RR_A_msg = dynamic_cast< CDns_RR_A* >( &msg )

                                    uint32 address;

                                    dnsclass = CLASS_IN;
                                    RR_A_msg->dclass = dnsclass;
                                    dnstype = TYPE_A;
                                    RR_A_msg->type = dnstype;

                                    res = DecodeInt32(&buffer,&size,&ttl);
                                    CHECK_DECODE_ERROR(res);
                                    RR_A_msg->m_ttl = ttl;

                                    res = DecodeInt32(&buffer,&size,&address);
                                    CHECK_DECODE_ERROR(res);
                                    RR_A_msg->m_address = address;
                            }
```

Changing uint32_t to uint32 for decode worked, and having RR_A_msg-> instead of msg. worked too. 
But now i have `undefined reference to`typeinfo for CDns_RR_A'`

Comment: `if(CDns_RR_A* RR_A_msg = dynamic_cast< CDns_RR_A* >( &msg ))` looks unusual. Just write `if(dynamic_cast< CDns_RR_A* >( &msg ) != nullptr)`.

Comment: I just changed thanks to your advice. But to do 
" RR_A_msg->m_address"
i still have to initialize the way i did the RR_A_

Comment: `RR_A_msg` is not used in the code. You don't need a temporary for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "you cannot convert uint32_t* to uint32" the issue is that the former is a pointer and the later is not. You should take the & off the front and pass the value not a pointer to it.

I don't know why you can't get the class member (maybe related to using a reserved name as a variable?) but you shouldn't be able to access m_address in this way.

Instead of

```
msg.m_address
```

You need to be using

```
RR_A_msg->m_address
```

Comment: Thanks, just used it, it works perfectly for the uint.
For the msg.m_address i used your solution (i got less errorrs)
but i have this one now : "undefined reference to `typeinfo for CDns_RR_A'"

Comment: This post has some possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307352/g-undefined-reference-to-typeinfo.   Possibly you need the override specifier on your virtual functions in CDns_RR_A

Comment: It's the function signature of getSize on the derived class. It needs to be the same as that on the base. You also shouldn't need the instance of the base class passed in because the members of the base are available in the derived class

Comment: But when i call my function i don't know if i have an A record object or SRV so i have to pass a generic object : CDnsMessage no ?

Comment: I tried to comment Getsize in the .h and .cpp to see if this remove the error but it still can't compile.

Comment: You should read up about polymorphism in c++, you need to call that function against an object that either is or derives from your base.