# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: typeinfo for leveldb::Comparator"

Tags: c++, leveldb

I am trying to compile and link following code with leveldb on Mac:

```
#include "leveldb/comparator.h"

class KeyComparator: public leveldb::Comparator {
public:
        virtual ~KeyComparator() {}

        virtual int Compare(const leveldb::Slice& a, const leveldb::Slice& b) const  {
                return 0;
        }

        virtual const char* Name() const  {
                return "test";
        }

        virtual void FindShortestSeparator(std::string* start, const leveldb::Slice& limit) const  {
        }

        virtual void FindShortSuccessor(std::string* key) const  {
        }
};
int main() {
        KeyComparator comp;
        return 0;
}
```

```
git clone https://github.com/google/leveldb.git
cd leveldb/
mkdir -p build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. && cmake --build .
g++  -I leveldb/include/ -L leveldb/build/ -l leveldb test.cpp
```

But got following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for leveldb::Comparator", referenced from:
      typeinfo for KeyComparator in test-d20952.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Does any one know where is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This is my g++ versions: ```Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4184877/7699037) should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes,adding -fno-rtti solved the problem g++  -I leveldb/include/ -fno-rtti test.cpp -Llib -lleveldb, Thanks